# How to force kill another application in cocoa Mac OS X 10.5

Tags: cocoa, kill, sigkill, nsworkspace, appleevents

I've this task, from my application i need to **kill** another my application, the problem is that the **other application has a Termination *Confirm Dialog*** (there is no critical data to save, only confirmation of user intent to quit).

- On 10.6+ you will use:

  ```
  bool TerminatedAtLeastOne = false;

  // For OS X >= 10.6 NSWorkspace has the nifty runningApplications-method.
  if ([NSRunningApplication respondsToSelector:@selector(runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:)]) {
      for (NSRunningApplication *app in [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.company.applicationName"]) {
          [app forceTerminate];
          TerminatedAtLeastOne = true;
      }
      return TerminatedAtLeastOne;
  }
  ```
- but on <10.6 this commonly used Apple Event:

  ```
  // If that didn‘t work either... then try using the apple event method, also works for OS X < 10.6.
  AppleEvent event = {typeNull, nil};
  const char *bundleIDString = "com.company.applicationName";

  OSStatus result = AEBuildAppleEvent(kCoreEventClass, kAEQuitApplication, typeApplicationBundleID, bundleIDString, strlen(bundleIDString), kAutoGenerateReturnID, kAnyTransactionID, &event, NULL, "");

  if (result == noErr) {
      result = AESendMessage(&event, NULL, kAENoReply|kAEAlwaysInteract, kAEDefaultTimeout);
      AEDisposeDesc(&event);
  }
  return result == noErr;
  ```

  can't Force Quit!!!

So what can you use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this simple code that I've digged out on *cocoabuilder*:

```
// If that didn‘t work then try shoot it in the head, also works for OS X < 10.6.
NSArray *runningApplications = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchedApplications];
NSString *theName;
NSNumber *pid;
for ( NSDictionary *applInfo in runningApplications ) {
    if ( (theName = [applInfo objectForKey:@"NSApplicationName"]) ) {
        if ( (pid = [applInfo objectForKey:@"NSApplicationProcessIdentifier"]) ) {
            //NSLog( @"Process %@ has pid:%@", theName, pid );    //test
            if( [theName isEqualToString:@"applicationName"] ) {
                kill( [pid intValue], SIGKILL );
                TerminatedAtLeastOne = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
return TerminatedAtLeastOne;
```