# Close other applications using swift

Tags: macos, swift

Is there a way to close running applications in swift? For instance, if the application I create needs to close safari.

Comment: this might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919389/how-to-force-kill-another-application-in-cocoa-mac-os-x-10-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly possible via an applescript directly IF:

**your app is not running sandboxed (note that if you plan to distribute it via the App Store, your app will be sandboxed)**
OR
your app has the necessary entitlements to use applescript: `com.apple.security.scripting-targets` (**apple needs to approve that AND you need to know which apps to target. this isn't a blanket permission**)

**then**

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60401/how-do-i-create-an-applescript-that-will-quit-an-application-at-a-specific-time
- [Can you execute an Applescript script from a Swift Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163433/can-you-execute-an-applescript-script-from-a-swift-application)

---

if you aren't going for App Store complicity anyways, you might also use NSTask directly
scripts / code snippets:

- [How to force kill another application in cocoa Mac OS X 10.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919389/how-to-force-kill-another-application-in-cocoa-mac-os-x-10-5)
- [Can you execute an Applescript script from a Swift Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163433/can-you-execute-an-applescript-script-from-a-swift-application)

---

short & sweet: technically yes, 'politically' maybe :D

Answer (score 5):

Here's a Swift 5 version for closing running applications **without using AppleScript** (AppleScript is a perfect way but it isn't the only way), Safari is used as the example in this case:

```
let runningApplications = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications
if let safari = runningApplications.first(where: { (application) in
    return application.bundleIdentifier == "com.apple.Safari" && application.bundleURL == URL(fileURLWithPath: NSWorkspace.shared.fullPath(forApplication: "Safari")!)
}) {
    // option 1
    safari.terminate()
    // option 2
    kill(safari.processIdentifier, SIGTERM)
}
```

SIGTERM instead of SIGKILL, referencing from [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-SIGINT-and-SIGTERM-signals-in-Linux-What%E2%80%99s-the-difference-between-the-SIGKILL-and-SIGSTOP-signals)

Of course, **make sure you notify the user of this activity** since this may cause negative impact on the user-experience (for example, user-generated contents in the targeted application are not saved before terminating)

Comment: this is great if you are completely unsandboxed and if you wanna kill the app directly