# Terminate another running application from one application

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to create app which will detect and show the list of all running application and i can close other application from that app.

Below is the code to open the application. But is their any way to close the another running applications

```
  NSString *customURL = @"iOSDevTips://";

      if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]])
      {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
      }
```

Is this possible in objective C or swift?

If yes what are the chances for its acceptance by apple review team

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can't do that in iOS.

Don't worry about what other applications are open. The OS will take care of closing them if necessary.

Comment: I get this :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576466/close-other-applications-using-swift

Comment: Is that means it is possible by using swift?

Comment: No. That question is about Mac OS X, not iOS.